# new to this - django-nonrel / social-auth

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, django-socialauth

I'm trying to implement django-social-auth on a google app engine project, but I keep getting an error that says:

```
raise NotImplementedError("The database backend only supports "
NotImplementedError: The database backend only supports count() queries.
```

The main page works, but I get that error whenever I click any of the login links.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The full text of the error is below (I shortened some of the directories).  Thank you so much in advance for any help.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/login/google-oauth2/

Django Version: 1.4.3
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'djangotoolbox',
 'autoload',
 'dbindexer',
 'httplib2',
 'openid',
 'oauth2',
 'social_auth',
 'djangoappengine')
Installed Middleware:
('autoload.middleware.AutoloadMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  188.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py" in process_response
  36.                 request.session.save()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\contrib\sessions\backends\cached_db.py" in save
  42.         super(SessionStore, self).save(must_create)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in save
  51.             session_key=self._get_or_create_session_key(),
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in _get_or_create_session_key
  145.             self._session_key = self._get_new_session_key()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in _get_new_session_key
  139.             if not self.exists(session_key):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\contrib\sessions\backends\cached_db.py" in exists
  39.         return super(SessionStore, self).exists(session_key)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in exists
  27.         return Session.objects.filter(session_key=session_key).exists()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\db\models\query.py" in exists
  565.             return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in has_results
  441.         return bool(compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE))
File ".\app project directory\dbindexer\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  24.         return super(SQLCompiler, self).execute_sql(*args, **kwargs)
File ".\app project directory\djangotoolbox\db\basecompiler.py" in execute_sql
  364.         raise NotImplementedError("The database backend only supports "

Exception Type: NotImplementedError at /login/google-oauth2/
Exception Value: The database backend only supports count() queries.
```

Comment: U will not able to run complex relational queries with `django-nonrel`.

Comment: gae supports SQL now, use that for django for a simpler life.